# RDLC Grouping Changes my Sort

Tags: c#, rdlc

I have a simple report which is to be sorted by date.

If I sort by date without grouping, everything is fine. As soon as I add my group, the data is no longer sorted by date.

I have tried added interactive sorting for "Date" on every column and still no luck.

Is there something I am missing? This must be possible!

PS: My data is sorted by date with the SQL.

Comment: have a look into http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157462(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did not notice the group automatically added sorting. I fixed this right-clicking the Group, and under sorting I deleted the sort field.

Answer (score 0):

Even I spent a day trying to fix the same issue. The trick is edit the 'Group Properties'
Right click on the cell you are grouping by. Go to Row Group > Group Properties
Click the Tab called Sorting and then add the expression or column you would like to sort on.